# How to get the list of inactive devices using consumer option of camel apns component?

Tags: apple-push-notifications, apache-camel

Can someone please guide me on how to get the list of inactive iOS devices after we have consumed feedback from the "apns:consumer" to "mock:result" as given on apns component webpage.It says that the feedback stream gives information about inactive devices but how to retrieve that information.Is there some way to get the inactive devices token id in an array-list?Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation the inactive device information will be in the body:

> When Camel will fetch feedback data corresponding to inactive devices,
>   it will retrieve a List of InactiveDevice objects. Each InactiveDevice
>   object of the retrieved list will be setted as the In body, and then
>   processed by the consumer endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

From http://camel.apache.org/apns.html -
"When Camel will fetch feedback data corresponding to inactive devices, it will retrieve a List of InactiveDevice objects. Each InactiveDevice object of the retrieved list will be setted as the In body, and then processed by the consumer endpoint."

You can check in the test how to fetch the InactiveDevice.
https://code.google.com/p/camel-apns/source/browse/trunk/src/test/java/org/apache/camel/component/apns/spring/SpringApnsConsumerTest.java

`InactiveDevice inactiveDevice = (InactiveDevice)mock.getExchanges().get(0).getIn().getBody();`